# why does my session cookie not expires?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, session-cookies

I was developing a rails app with user sign-in function.

I was using a **auth_token** in browser's cookie to identify user in a session.

But it seems that, every time I close the browser, the use automatically logged in;
and the **auth_token** is still there.

Here is what I was doing in the code:

```
if login_params[:remember_me] == "1"
    cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
  else
    cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
  end
```

I think that, when the "remember_me" is not checked, this **auth_token** expires after a browser restarts.

I used "web developer" to check the cookie, and it shows that **auth_token** expires 
at the end of a session.

Since it expires at the end of a session, why is it still there after I restart my browser?

Comment: you might have to manually set the expire time when setting the cookie

Comment: @jquadrin I just set the auth_token cookie to expire after 1 second, and it works.

Comment: @jquadrin But still, I'd like to ask: the "expire at the end of session" in browser not worked as I expected; or this is just a common  approach the we deal with session cookies?

Comment: I find it to be a common approach for me because it the only thing which seems to work dependably

Answer (score 1):

you should manually set the expire time when setting the cookie. I find it to be a common approach for me because its the only thing which seems to be dependable.

I would set it to expire in 6 - 10 hours after creation.